# Setting NSOutputStream to be synchronous

Tags: ios, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, synchronous

I know there are few questions similar to this one, but in all cases the answer is to make it asynchronous.

According to the apple documentation (even though it is not recommended) [polling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/PollingVersusRunloop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002275-CJBEDDBG) is an available option. However, I just couldn't implement it.

- Should probably mention I am doing it in c# using Xamarin, but if you
  can give me an answer on how to do this in Objective-C that would be
  good too.

Here is my attempt

```
while(true)
  {
    if (outStream.HasSpaceAvailable())
      {
        int output = ((NSOutputStream)outStream).Write(data, (uint)data.Count());
      }
  }
```

The problem here is that `outStream.HasSpaceAvailable()` is false indefinitely.

**Reason why I want to do it synchronously:**

Currently (in a test app) I am doing it asynchronously and it works for sending one stream of data per call to the method. However in the real App I will need to send lots of small data packets one after the other. Therefore, I need to wait for the data to be sent before I can send another packet.

If I try putting many calls to the delegate the data keeps overwriting the previous call...

It would be great if you could let me know how to do it synchronously first (for the sake of having one answer out there on it). If you think there is a better way to do it in an async way let me know too.

Thanks

**EDIT :**
Here is how I set up the session

```
SESSION=new EASession (Accessory, Protocol);
NSStreamStatus outputStream= SESSION.OutputSream;
outputStream.Open();
```

This is done when a button is pressed and before the while loop above (obviously).

Comment: Where is your output stream coming from?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RichardJ.RossIII 
Not entirely sure what you mean, but I edited the question to show how the session is set up. Let me know if that is what you meant or not

Comment: I think you should still use the asynchronous version of the APIs. If you need to throttle the packets so only one thread is sending at a time, then that isn't a valid reason to make something that should be asynchronous synchronous. Use [C# locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) like a proper gentlemen.